SST RDS Construct: Kysely migration failing
I need to create a PostgreSQL table to use for text search, and I read in the documentation that I have to use Kysely ORM for the migrations. I had multiple issues with it, but now I got it to a point where I can run the migrations, but I get a mysterious error, with no way to debug it. The error I get is this:
Error: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block; SQLState: 25P02

And this is my migration file:
import { Kysely, sql } from 'kysely';

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
export async function up(db: Kysely<any>): Promise<void> {
  db.schema
    .createTable('media')
    .addColumn('id', 'serial', (col) => col.primaryKey())
    //...etc
    .addColumn('description', 'text', (col) => col.notNull())
    .addColumn('tsv', sql`tsvector`, (col) => col.generatedAlwaysAs(sql`to_tsvector('german', description)`))
    .execute();

  db.schema.createIndex('tsvector_idx').on('media').column('tsv').execute();
}

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
export async function down(db: Kysely<any>): Promise<void> {
  await db.schema.dropIndex('tsvector_idx').execute();
  await db.schema.dropTable('media').execute();
}

By using trial - and - error, I found out that the problem is in this line of code:
.addColumn('tsv', sql`tsvector`, (col) => col.generatedAlwaysAs(sql`to_tsvector('german', description)`))

I can't see an alternative to this.
EDIT:
After some work, I managed to create a debug SQL query and actually see what the Kysely ORM generates. The error is there, it's not form the Typescript code or anything. Previously I have omitted the full table structure for clarity (and this is why the generated SQL query has more tables in it), but I am pretty sure, that this is not the problem. Here's the query generated by the ORM:
create table "media" (
  "id" serial primary key,
  "media_id" varchar(50) not null, 
  "format" varchar(20) not null, 
  "width" integer, 
  "height" integer, 
  "copyright" text not null, 
  "description" text not null, 
  "tsv" tsvector generated always as (to_tsvector('german', description))
);


Can you add await in creation phase before db.schema like what you did in drop ?

a very nice catch, thank you. I added the await statements, but I get another mysterious error: Error: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"   Position: 274; SQLState: 42601 

I didn't see any misplaced prenthesis, but can you replace table creation with "await db.schema
.createTable('media')
.addColumn('id', 'serial', (col) => col.primaryKey())
.addColumn('description', 'text', (col) => col.notNull())
.addColumn('tsv', sqltsvector, (col) =>
col.generatedAlwaysAs(sqlto_tsvector('german', description)).stored()
)
.execute();" Sorry for the formatting I didn't get it right in the comment

Thanks so much for the help! I managed to generate a debug query, and now am sure the problem is in the SQL query. I have updated the question with the new information. Cheers!

After some debugging, it turned out that in order to have a generated column working as expected, you need to specify that it is "stored". This worked after changing it to the following:
import { Kysely, sql } from 'kysely';

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
export async function up(db: Kysely<any>): Promise<void> {
  db.schema
    .createTable('media')
    .addColumn('id', 'serial', (col) => col.primaryKey())
    //...etc
    .addColumn('description', 'text', (col) => col.notNull())
    .addColumn('tsv', sql`tsvector`, (col) => col.generatedAlwaysAs(sql`to_tsvector('german', description)`).stored())
    .execute();

  db.schema.createIndex('tsvector_idx').on('media').column('tsv').execute();
}

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
export async function down(db: Kysely<any>): Promise<void> {
  await db.schema.dropIndex('tsvector_idx').execute();
  await db.schema.dropTable('media').execute();
}

Which results in the following SQL:
create table "media" (
  "id" serial primary key,
  "media_id" varchar(50) not null, 
  "format" varchar(20) not null, 
  "width" integer, 
  "height" integer, 
  "copyright" text not null, 
  "description" text not null, 
  "tsv" tsvector generated always as (to_tsvector('german', description)) stored
);

